# Homebrew R build missing Cairo

Tags: macos, r, homebrew, cairo, cran

I installed R on an OSX 10.7.5 server using brew:

```
brew install R
```

Everything seems so OK far, however Cairo is not working:

```
> svg(tempfile())
Warning messages:
1: In svg(tempfile()) :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/Cellar/r/2.15.2/R.framework/Resources/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so':
  dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/r/2.15.2/R.framework/Resources/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so, 6): image not found
2: In svg(tempfile()) : failed to load cairo DLL
```

The shared object file seems to be missing completely:

```
id-86-243:Resources jeroen$ ls -ltr library/grDevices/libs/
total 488
-rwxrwxr-x  1 jeroen  admin  245764 Dec 22 17:03 grDevices.so
```

I rarely use OSX, so I am not quite sure if this is a bug in this particular distribution of R, or if I have done something wrong when building it?

Comment: ISTR that Simon Urbanek discourages people from using homebrew to compile R. On Nov 4 2012 in the MacSIG he wrote: "You can't use CRAN binaries with homebrew. If you use homebrew, you're entirely on your own and you have to build everything from sources."

Comment: That's fine. In Linux we always install packages from source as well. grDevices is base R though.

Comment: The default packages include both 'base' and 'grDevices', but grDevices is not in the 'base' package.

Comment: When installing R using macports, I have to make sure that I install r-framework and not just R. Maybe there is a similar issue with brew? I suggest to use macports.

Comment: @DWin I was referring to its priority: http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/grDevices/DESCRIPTION.in

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just ran into this problem. It seems to be a problem with `pkg-config` locating `cairo` during the R configure stage. The workaround seems to be:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig
```

so that R can properly use `cairo`.

I install R directly from source, rather than with `homebrew`, but I do use `homebrew` to keep other libraries up to date. This resolves the problem for me.

For reference, I am running OSX Mavericks.

Comment: Installing from source in homebrew (i.e. as `brew install R --build-from-source`) caused R to be linked to the appropriate cairo library for me.

Answer (score 1):

What finally worked for me was building R explicitly with cairo (brew's default R tap uses `--without-cairo` and simply editing the tap did not solve the issue for me).

It's all explained in this nice blog post: https://luispuerto.net/blog/2018/05/11/installing-r-with-homebrew-with-all-the-capabilities/

Works like a charm for me with R 4.0.2, cairo 1.16.0_3 under macOS Catalina 10.15.6.